# Timer Interval Calling Long Method

Tags: c#, timer

What would happen with the code below if `Execute()` takes, say, 3000ms to finish, but is being called every 1000ms due to the timer interval?

```
        Timer _timer = new Timer();        
        private void setupTimer()
        {
            _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(pollingTimeElapsed);
            _timer.Interval = 1000;
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void pollingTimeElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Execute();
        }
```

EDIT: I am using System.Windows.Forms.Timer, since System.Timers.Timer doesn't have .Tick

Comment: Are you using System.Timers.Timer or System.Windows.Forms.Timer?

Comment: Don't wonder about what would happen! Just stop the timer, Execute() and start the timer again.

Comment: System.Windows.Timer has a Tick event, System.Timers.Timer has an Elapsed event. System.Timers.Timer has my preference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using the System.Timers.Timer class.

Since AutoReset has the default value (which is True), the Elapsed event will be fired for each time 1000ms has elapsed.

If you want to fire the event only one time, set AutoReset to False.

If you do not want to fire the event while your execute-code is running, do the following:

```
Timer _timer = new Timer();        
private void setupTimer() {
    _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(pollingTimeElapsed);
    _timer.Interval = 1000;
    _timer.Enabled = true;
    _timer.Start();
}

private void pollingTimeElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        _timer.Stop()
        Execute();
    } finally {
        _timer.Start()
    }
}
```

Comment: _timer.Enabled = true; and _timer.Start(); is redundant.

Comment: There is a possible race issue when stopping the timer in the elapsed event.